# Linq GroupBy multiple columns with Projection to new object

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version 3.1.3:

I have the following object:

```
public class OrganisationMention
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
    public int PublicationId { get; set; }
    public Publication Publication { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int PracticeAreaId { get; set; }
    public PracticeArea PracticeArea { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int MarketAverage { get; set; }
}
```

I want to aggregate a list of OrganisationMentions by Publication\Location\PracticeArea to get a list of RelatedOrganisationMentions objects with a Sum of the Count like the following:

```
public class RelatedOrganisationMentions
{
    public int PublicationId { get; set; }
    public Publication Publication { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int PracticeAreaId { get; set; }
    public PracticeArea PracticeArea { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int MarketAverage { get; set; }
}
```

If I use the following LINQ query I get a horrid error relating to the projection of the Publication\Location\PracticeArea Objects. If I omit them then the query returns fine. I do however want them back in the aggregated result and can guarantee that each Publication object will be the same entity if the PublicationId is the same:

```
        IQueryable<RelatedOrganisationMentions> relatedOrganisationMentions = collection
            .GroupBy(m => new { m.LocationId, m.PublicationId, m.PracticeAreaId })
            .Select(am => new RelatedOrganisationMentions
            {
                PracticeArea = am.First().PracticeArea, //Causes long and horrid error
                Location = am.First().Location,         //Causes long and horrid error
                Publication = am.First().Publication,   //Causes long and horrid error
                PracticeAreaId = am.Key.PracticeAreaId,
                PublicationId = am.Key.PublicationId,
                LocationId = am.Key.LocationId,
                Count = am.Sum(x => x.Count)
            })
        .OrderBy(r => r.Publication.Description)
        .ThenBy(r => r.PracticeArea.Description);

    return await relatedOrganisationMentions.ToListAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

How do I Group by multiple columns and preserve the objects in the aggregated projection, please?

ERROR

> System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression
> '(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new {
> LocationId = EntityMaterializerSource.TryReadValue(grouping.Key, 0, Property:
> OrganisationMention.LocationId (int) Required FK Index),
> PublicationId = EntityMaterializerSource.TryReadValue(grouping.Key, 1, Property:
> OrganisationMention.PublicationId (int) Required FK Index),
> PracticeAreaId = EntityMaterializerSource.TryReadValue(grouping.Key, 2, Property:
> OrganisationMention.PracticeAreaId (int) Required FK Index)  },
> ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: OrganisationMention
> ValueBufferExpression:
> (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> IsNullable: False ) )
> .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(),
> ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> at

UPDATE 1: Looks like this is a known issue with efcore 3.1 Looking now for possible workarounds.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12088

Comment: `GroupBy` support in EF core 3 is limited to the most simple cases only (group by primitive properties and selecting nothing but key properties + aggregates). For anything else you have to find work-arounds. It's not just that `First` isn't translatable (although it isn't), the entire `GroupBy` will fail, whatever you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `First()` could not be translated by Linq to SQL. You need to use `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
...
PracticeArea = am.FirstOrDefault().PracticeArea,
Location = am.FirstOrDefault().Location,
Publication = am.FirstOrDefault().Publication,
...
```

**Edit** Proposed solution to avoid errors:

*Required access to:* `context.PracticeAreas`, `context.Locations` and `context.Publications`

```
IQueryable<RelatedOrganisationMentions> relatedOrganisationMentions = collection
    .GroupBy(
        m => new { m.LocationId, m.PublicationId, m.PracticeAreaId },
        (k, g) => new{ k.LocationId, k.PublicationId, k.PracticeAreaId, Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count) }
    )
    .Select(am => new RelatedOrganisationMentions
    {
        PracticeArea = context.PracticeAreas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == am.PracticeAreaId),
        Location = context.Locations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == am.LocationId),
        Publication = context.Publications.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == am.PublicationId),
        PracticeAreaId = am.PracticeAreaId,
        PublicationId = am.PublicationId,
        LocationId = am.LocationId,
        Count = x.Count
    })
    .OrderBy(r => r.Publication.Description)
    .ThenBy(r => r.PracticeArea.Description);
```

Comment: Same error I'm afraid. ".FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated"

Comment: @sarin please check the edit. I've not tested this code, but it should work for you.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting an error on Count = am.Sum(x => x.Count), presumably as it wasn't included in the second clause of the GroupBy. So added: new { k.LocationId, k.PublicationId, k.PracticeAreaId, Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count) } . Its now working.  The way the PracticeAreas\Locations\Publications are returned in the select now, would they be executed once for each row ? i.e. could this generate many individual select statements and potentially be inefficient? Might a separate statement post this query which joins those tables in once be more performant?

Comment: I forgot the `Count` column :D. Will update the answer.... The solution will generate a `LEFT JOIN` to retrieve `PracticeAreas\Locations\Publications`; right now I don't know how to make this query in a better way. Try to write it your self in plain SQL to compare; you will need to make something like this to select the `PracticeAreas\Locations\Publications` columns. You can enable [EF Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3) to display the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

Usually it is enough to first `Select` the property that you want, followed by `FirstOrDefault`:

```
PracticeArea = am.Select(amItem => amItem.PracticeArea)
    .FirstOrDefault(),
Location = am.Select(amItem => amItem.Location)
    .FirstOrDefault(),
Publication = am.Select(amItem => amItem.Publication)
    .FirstOrDefault(),
```

### Explanation of the error

You have to be aware of the difference between an `IEnumerable<...>` and an 'IQueryable<...>`.

An IEnumerable is meant to be executed by your own process. It holds everything to fetch the first element, and once you've got it, you can get the next element, as long as there are elements.

On lowest level this is done using `GetEnumerator()`. Once you've got the enumerator, you can access the elements of the sequence one by one using repeatedly `MoveNext()` and `Current`.

On higher level this is done using a `foreach`. This is also done in every LINQ method that doesn't return `IEnumerable<...>`

On the other hand, an `IQueryable<...>` is meant to be processed by another process, usually a database management system. It holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The Expression represents the query in some generic format, the Provider knows who must execute the query, and what language is used to communicate with the database (usually SQL).

If you look closely to LINQ methods, you'll see that there are two groups: those that return `IQueryable<...>` (or `IEnumerable<...>`), and the others. Methods of the first group use deferred execution (sometimes called lazy execution). In every description of these LINQ method you will find this term.

These functions won't communicate with the database, they will only change the Expression. Concatenating these functions is not an expensive operation.

Only when you start enumerating, al low level using `GetEnumerator()`, or by using `foreach`, or any of the LINQ method of the second group, like `ToList()`, ``Count()`,` Any()`, etc. the Expression is sent to the Provider who will try to translate it into SQL and execute the query at the database.

The problem is that the Provider does not know how to translate all methods into SQL. For instance, it doesn't know your own methods. Furthermore, there are several LINQ methods that are not supported. See [List of supported and unsupported LINQ methods (LINQ to entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Your Provider can't translate your usage of `First()`:

```
...First()' could not be translated.
```